# Receive data from ESP32 with HTTPClient

Tags: esp32, http

I need to receive data from sensors on the websites located on my PC (hosted with XAMPP).

When I was first using AsyncWebServer library and hosting them on ESP32 everything was working with a combination of those two:

```
response = String(digitalRead(button1)) + "," +String(digitalRead(button2)) + "," +
                String(digitalRead(button3)) + "," +String(digitalRead(button4)) + "," +
                String(angleX) + "," + String(angleY) + "," +
                String(sensor1value);

server.on("/state", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  request->send(200, "text/plain", response);
  });
```

and:

```
setInterval(function ( ) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var Answer = this.responseText;
            console.log(Answer);
            let values = Answer.split(',');
            document.getElementById("led1").style.backgroundColor = (values[0] == 0) ? 'green' : 'red';
          }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "/state", true); 
        xhttp.send();
      }, 100 ) ;
```

JS script was linked on dashboard.html page and changed the appearance of elements on it according to the values.

Now I need the same result with HTTPClient

```
String serverName = "http://192.168.0.20/glove/state.html";

/*response = String(digitalRead(button1)) + "," + String(digitalRead(button2));*/

response = "?button1=" + String(digitalRead(button1)) +  "&button2=" + String(digitalRead(button2));
                      
/*response = "button1=" + String(digitalRead(button1)) +  "&button2=" + String(digitalRead(button2)); */

    WiFiClient client;
    HTTPClient http; 

    //String serverPath = serverName + response;
    String serverPath = serverName;  
    //Serial.println(serverPath);
    http.begin(client,serverPath);
    
    http.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //http.addHeader("Content-Type","text-plain");
    //http.POST(response);
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    //Serial.println(response);
    
    //int httpCode = http.sendRequest("POST",response);
    Serial.println(httpCode);
```

But I can't get it to work (was trying different combinations with GET and POST methods).

Comment: Why do you use `/glove/state.html` in the new client instead of just`/state`?

Comment: Please, show your attempt at using POST, as this is the relevant HTTP method. Are you sure you have WiFi connectivity? Are you able to send the data to your XAMPP server manually with either [curl](https://curl.se/) or [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/)? Can you capture the HTTP dialog with a network sniffer? Could you show us the on-the-wire requests, both a successful (with curl or HTTPie) and an unsuccessful one (with your HTTPClient code)? Comparing them should tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: I've written a set o ESP32 libraries. One of them is for a web server. Check it out here: https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonlabs-ESP32-C-Base-Firmware-Libraries#readme . ilnd "routes.cpp". Hope it helps

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer because with old library there was no additional file called "state" (or state.html or whatever) - it was declared in that server.on. When i tried using only "/state" with new library i was getting error that  there is no file/page with that name (so i created state.html)

Comment: @EdgarBonet i think i had connection with my xampp server, because when i was serial printing response status code i was getting 200 (or some error ones depending on my changes in code)